Why are x, y in a twin d3v7 force graph NaN? Why doesn't the data work properly?
I want to implement a dual-panel set of D3 force graphs (see below).

I use an adjacency list to split my original data into two graphs. There are two copies of everything, so individual elements can be retrieved or selected in future feature development
I have four steps in the graph setup corresponding to four functions in the namespace:

Function ns.initSVG(data, inputOptions) -> sets up the two svg's
Function ns.updateGraph(graph, options) -> splits the original graph into two graphs
Function ns.showGraphs(options) -> sets up all of the lines, labels and nodes
Function ns.simGraph(options) -> runs the simulations

For some reason x and y are both NaN. Why?
I have tried everything i can think of, including logging out data at various steps, but I can't find where my setup error is.
Can you help me find it please?
I have a working copy on VizHub here, but i also present the code and data below.
The namespace and adjacency list that drives the two graphs are

//----------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------
// Adjaceny List Class
//-------------------------------------------
class Graph {
  constructor() {
    this.t = new Map();
  }
  addEdge(node1, node2) {
    const s = this.t.get(node1);
    if (s == null) this.t.set(node1, new Set([node2]));
    else s.add(node2);
  }
  getAdjacencies(node) {
    var z = this.t.get(node);
    if (z == null) {
      z = new Set();
    }
    return z;
  }
  *dir(node, path = Array(), visited = new Set()) {
    yield [...path, node];
    path.push(node);
    visited.add(node);
    for (const adj of this.getAdjacencies(node)) {
      if (!visited.has(adj)) {
        yield* this.dir(adj, path, visited);
      }
    }
    path.pop();
  }
  *dirs(nodes) {
    for (const node of nodes) {
      yield* this.dir(node);
    }
  }
}

//------------------------------------------
// visualisation component
//-----------------------------------------
window.workP = {};
(function (ns) {
  // A. Initialise the object
  ns.initSVG = async function (data, inputOptions) {
    console.group('Step 1 initSVG');
    console.log(['config', data, inputOptions]);

    //copy inputOptions into options
    let options = Object.assign({}, inputOptions);

    if (options.theme === 'light') {
      options.theme = options.light_theme;
    } else {
      options.theme = options.dark_theme;
    }

    options.steps = [];
    options.steps.push('initSVG');
    //
    // Step 1: Setup the 3 svg's and the tooltip
    options.promotable_svg = d3
      .select('#working_svg')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', options.working_width)
      .attr('height', options.svg_height / 2)
      .attr('class', 'promotable_svg');
    options.scratch_svg = d3
      .select('#working_svg')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', options.working_width)
      .attr('height', options.svg_height / 2)
      .attr('class', 'scratch_svg');
    options.tooltip = d3
      .select('body')
      .append('div')
      .attr('class', 'tooltip')
      .style('opacity', 0);

    // Step 2: Setup the 3 rectangles
    options.promotable_rect = options.promotable_svg
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', options.working_width)
      .attr('height', options.svg_height / 2)
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('stroke', options.theme.svgBorder)
      .attr('fill', options.theme.promoFill);
    options.scratch_rect = options.scratch_svg
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', options.working_width)
      .attr('height', options.svg_height / 2)
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('stroke', options.theme.svgBorder)
      .attr('fill', options.theme.scratchFill);
    options.promotable_label = options.promotable_svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 10 + ',' + 20 + ')')
      .append('text')
      .text('Promotable')
      .style('fill', options.theme.svgName);
    options.scratch_label = options.scratch_svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 10 + ',' + 20 + ')')
      .append('text')
      .text('Scratch Pad')
      .style('fill', options.theme.svgName);

    // Step 3. Connect the svg's to the function object and set the zoom
    options.promo_svg = options.promotable_svg
      .call(
        d3.zoom().on('zoom', function () {
          options.promotable_svg.attr(
            'transform',
            event.transform,
          );
        }),
      )
      .append('g');
    options.scratch_svg = options.scratch_svg
      .call(
        d3.zoom().on('zoom', function () {
          options.scratch_svg.attr(
            'transform',
            event.transform,
          );
        }),
      )
      .append('g');

    // Append the Arrowhead in Promo and Scratch SVG's
    options.promo_svg = options.promo_svg
      .append('defs')
      .append('marker')
      .attr('id', 'parrowhead')
      .attr('viewBox', '-0 -5 10 10') 
      .attr('refX', 50) 
      .attr('refY', 0)
      .attr('orient', 'auto')
      .attr('markerWidth', 10)
      .attr('markerHeight', 10)
      .attr('xoverflow', 'visible')
      .append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
      .attr('fill', options.checkColour)
      .style('stroke', 'none');

    options.scratch_svg = options.scratch_svg
      .append('defs')
      .append('marker')
      .attr('id', 'sarrowhead')
      .attr('viewBox', '-0 -5 10 10') 
      .attr('refX', 50) 
      .attr('refY', 0)
      .attr('orient', 'auto')
      .attr('markerWidth', 10)
      .attr('markerHeight', 10)
      .attr('xoverflow', 'visible')
      .append('svg:path')
      .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
      .attr('fill', options.checkColour)
      .style('stroke', 'none');

    // Step 4. Setup the data, first separate the nodes and edges into two groups
    console.groupEnd();
    return options;
  };

  // Step 2: Split the Graph Data
  ns.updateGraph = async function (graph, options) {
    console.group('Step 2 updateGraph');
    console.log('options->', options);

    // let options = Object.assign({}, inputOptions);

    options.steps.push('updateGraph');
    // 1. Setup variables and define promotable types
    options.prom_types = [
      'incident',
      'task',
      'impact',
      'event',
      'sighting',
    ];
    let nodes = graph.nodes;
    let edges = graph.edges;

    options.split = {};
    options.split.promo = {};
    options.split.promo.nodes = [];
    options.split.promo.edges = [];
    options.split.scratch = {};
    options.split.scratch.nodes = [];
    options.split.scratch.edges = [];
    options.adjacency = new Graph();
    options.prom_node_IDs = [];

    // 2. Fill adjacency list with edges
    edges.forEach(function (edge) {
      options.adjacency.addEdge(
        edge['source'],
        edge['target'],
      );
    });
    //3. Find first the promotable node ID's and collect all sub-graphs into promID's
    nodes.forEach(function (node) {
      if (options.prom_types.includes(node.type)) {
        options.prom_node_IDs.push(node.id);
      }
    });
    options.prom_IDs = Array.from(
      options.adjacency.dirs(options.prom_node_IDs),
      (path) => path.at(-1),
    );
    // 4. Now split the Graphs and update the
    nodes.forEach(function (node) {
      if (options.prom_IDs.includes(node.id)) {
        options.split.promo.nodes.push(node);
      } else {
        options.split.scratch.nodes.push(node);
      }
    });
    edges.forEach(function (edge) {
      if (
        options.prom_IDs.includes(edge.source) &&
        options.prom_IDs.includes(edge.target)
      ) {
        options.split.promo.edges.push(edge);
      } else {
        options.split.scratch.edges.push(edge);
      }
    });
    // 5. Setup the namesspace data
    options.rawData = graph;

    console.log('options->', options);
    console.log('options.split->', options.split);
    console.log(
      'options.split.scratch->',
      options.split.scratch,
    );
    console.log(
      'options.split.promo->',
      options.split.promo,
    );

    console.groupEnd();
    return options;
  };

  // Step 3. Show Graph
  ns.showGraphs = async function (options) {
    console.group('Step 3 showGraphs');
    console.log('Showing the Graph');
    console.log('options->', options);
    options.steps.push('showGraphs');
    // Initialize the links, EdgePaths
    options.promoLink = options.promo_svg
      .selectAll('.plinks')
      .data(options.split.promo.edges)
      .join('line')
      .attr('class', 'plinks')
      .attr('source', (d) => d.source)
      .attr('target', (d) => d.target)
      .attr('stroke-width', 0.75)
      .attr('stroke', 'grey')
      .attr('marker-end', 'url(#parrowhead)'); //The marker-end attribute defines the arrowhead or polymarker that will be drawn at the final vertex of the given shape.

    options.scratchLink = options.scratch_svg
      .selectAll('.slinks')
      .data(options.split.scratch.edges)
      .join('line')
      .attr('class', 'slinks')
      .attr('source', (d) => d.source)
      .attr('target', (d) => d.target)
      .attr('stroke-width', 0.75)
      .attr('stroke', 'grey')
      .attr('marker-end', 'url(#sarrowhead)'); //The marker-end attribute defines the arrowhead or polymarker that will be drawn at the final vertex of the given shape.

    options.promoEdgepaths = options.promo_svg
      .selectAll('.pedgepath') //make path go along with the link provide position for link labels
      .data(options.split.promo.edges)
      .join('path')
      .attr('class', 'pedgepath')
      .attr('fill-opacity', 0)
      .attr('stroke-opacity', 0)
      .attr('id', function (d, i) {
        return 'pedgepath' + i;
      })
      .style('pointer-events', 'none');

    options.scratchEdgepaths = options.scratch_svg
      .selectAll('.sedgepath') //make path go along with the link provide position for link labels
      .data(options.split.scratch.edges)
      .join('path')
      .attr('class', 'sedgepath')
      .attr('fill-opacity', 0)
      .attr('stroke-opacity', 0)
      .attr('id', function (d, i) {
        return 'sedgepath' + i;
      })
      .style('pointer-events', 'none');

    options.promoEdgelabels = options.promo_svg
      .selectAll('.pedgelabel')
      .data(options.split.promo.edges)
      .join('text')
      .style('pointer-events', 'none')
      .attr('class', 'pedgelabel')
      .attr('id', function (d, i) {
        return 'pedgelabel' + i;
      })
      .attr('font-size', 18)
      .attr('fill', options.theme.edges);

    options.scratchEdgelabels = options.scratch_svg
      .selectAll('.sedgelabel')
      .data(options.split.scratch.edges)
      .join('text')
      .style('pointer-events', 'none')
      .attr('class', 'sedgelabel')
      .attr('id', function (d, i) {
        return 'sedgelabel' + i;
      })
      .attr('font-size', 18)
      .attr('fill', options.theme.edges);

    options.promoEdgelabels
      .append('textPath') //To render text along the shape of a <path>, enclose the text in a <textPath> element that has an href attribute with a reference to the <path> element.
      .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) {
        return '#pedgepath' + i;
      })
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .style('pointer-events', 'none')
      .attr('startOffset', '50%')
      .text((d) => d.name);

    options.scratchEdgelabels
      .append('textPath') //To render text along the shape of a <path>, enclose the text in a <textPath> element that has an href attribute with a reference to the <path> element.
      .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) {
        return '#sedgepath' + i;
      })
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .style('pointer-events', 'none')
      .attr('startOffset', '50%')
      .text((d) => d.name);

    // Initialize the nodes with attached image, changed to join data
    options.promoNode = options.promo_svg
      .append('g')
      .selectAll('.pnodes')
      .data(options.split.promo.nodes)
      .join('image')
      .attr('class', 'pnodes')
      .attr('xlink:href', function (d) {
        return (
          options.prefix + options.shape + d.icon + '.svg'
        );
      })
      .attr('width', options.icon_size + 5)
      .attr('height', options.icon_size + 5);
    

    // for scratch
    options.scratchNode = options.scratch_svg
      .append('g')
      .selectAll('.snodes')
      .data(options.split.scratch.nodes)
      .join('image')
      .attr('class', 'snodes')
      .attr('xlink:href', function (d) {
        return (
          options.prefix + options.shape + d.icon + '.svg'
        );
      })
      .attr('width', options.icon_size + 5)
      .attr('height', options.icon_size + 5);
    
    console.groupEnd();
    return options;
  };

  // Step 4: Ryn the simulation
  ns.simGraph = async function (options) {
    console.group('Step 4 simGraph');
    console.log('Simulating Graph');
    // console.log('inputOptions->', inputOptions);
    // let options = Object.assign({}, inputOptions);
    console.log('options->', options);
    options.steps.push('simGraph');
    console.log(
      'options.split.scratch->',
      options.split.promo.edges,
    );
    // Step 6. Setup the simulations
    // first the variables centreStrength
    options.pforceNode = d3.forceManyBody();
    options.sforceNode = d3.forceManyBody();
    options.pforceLink = d3
      .forceLink(options.split.promo.edges)
      .id((d) => d.id)
      .distance(4 * options.icon_size);
    options.sforceLink = d3
      .forceLink(options.split.scratch.edges)
      .id((d) => d.id)
      .distance(4 * options.icon_size);
    options.sforceCentre = d3.forceCenter(
      options.working_width / 2,
      options.svg_height / 4,
    );
    options.pforceCentre = d3.forceCenter(
      options.working_width / 2,
      options.svg_height / 4,
    );
    if (options.nodeStrength !== undefined)
      options.pforceNode.strength(options.nodeStrength);
    if (options.nodeStrength !== undefined)
      options.sforceNode.strength(options.nodeStrength);
    if (options.linkStrength !== undefined)
      options.pforceLink.strength(options.linkStrength);
    if (options.linkStrength !== undefined)
      options.sforceLink.strength(options.linkStrength);
    if (options.centreStrength !== undefined)
      options.sforceCentre.strength(options.centreStrength);
    if (options.centreStrength !== undefined)
      options.pforceCentre.strength(options.centreStrength);

    console.log(
      'options.split.promo.nodes',
      options.split.promo.nodes,
    );
    console.log(
      'options.split.promo.edges',
      options.split.promo.edges,
    );
    console.log(
      'options.split.scratch.nodes',
      options.split.scratch.nodes,
    );
    console.log(
      'options.split.scratch.edges',
      options.split.scratch.edges,
    );
    //

    options.promotable_sim = d3
      .forceSimulation(
        options.working_width,
        options.svg_height / 2,
      )
      .nodes(options.split.promo.nodes)
      .force('link', options.pforceLink)
      .force('charge', options.pforceNode)
      .force('center', options.pforceCentre)
      .on('tick', function () {
        // console.log(['promotable_sim ticked',this, options.promo_svg
        // .selectAll('.plinks')]);
        // options.promo_svg
        options.promoLink
          // .selectAll('.plinks')
          .attr('x1', (d) => d.source.x)
          .attr('y1', (d) => d.source.y)
          .attr('x2', (d) => d.target.x)
          .attr('y2', (d) => d.target.y);

        // options.promo_svg
        options.promoNode
          // .selectAll('.pnodes')
          // .attr('x', (d) => d.x - 6 / 2)
          .attr('x', function (d) {
            // console.log('promoNode->', d);
            return d.x - 6 / 2;
          })
          .attr('y', (d) => d.y - 6 / 2);

        // options.promo_svg.selectAll('.pedgepath')
        options.promoEdgepaths.attr(
          'd',
          function (d) {
            //console.log('pedgepath->', d);
            return (
              'M ' +
              d.source.x +
              ' ' +
              d.source.y +
              ' L ' +
              d.target.x +
              ' ' +
              d.target.y
            );
          },
        );
      }); 

    options.scratch_sim = d3
      .forceSimulation(
        options.working_width,
        options.svg_height / 2,
      )
      .nodes(options.split.scratch.nodes)
      .force('link', options.sforceLink)
      .force('charge', options.sforceNode)
      .force('center', options.sforceCentre)
      .on('tick', function () {
        // options.scratch_svg
        //   .selectAll('.slinks')
        options.scratchLink
          // .attr('d',
          //   function(d) {
          // console.log('slinks->', d);})
          .attr('x1', (d) => d.source.x)
          .attr('y1', (d) => d.source.y)
          .attr('x2', (d) => d.target.x)
          .attr('y2', (d) => d.target.y);

        // options.scratch_svg
        //   .selectAll('.snodes')
        options.scratchNode
          .attr('x', (d) => d.x - options.radius / 2)
          .attr('y', (d) => d.y - options.radius / 2);

        // options.scratch_svg.selectAll('.sedgepath')
        options.scratchEdgepaths.attr(
          'd',
          function (d) {
            // console.log('sedgepath->', d);
            return (
              'M ' +
              d.source.x +
              ' ' +
              d.source.y +
              ' L ' +
              d.target.x +
              ' ' +
              d.target.y
            );
          },
        );
      });

    // 7. Now show split graphs
    console.groupEnd();
    return options;
  };

  console.groupEnd();
  return 'function value';
})(workP); //execte declaration and pass namespace


I call the four functions using the code and options data below

const options = {
  duration: 350,
  radius: 6, // radius of curve for links
  barHeight: 40,
  margin: {
    top: 100,
    left: 30,
    bottom: 50,
    right: 30,
  },
  index_width: 400, // this svg
  working_width: 800, // next door svg
  svg_height: 800,
  svg_spacing: 500,
  // Icons
  prefix:
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/os-threat/images/main/img/',
  shape: 'rect-',
  icon_size: 36,
  textPadding: 8,
  corner: 5,
  // the tree view
  minHeight: 20,
  width: 400,
  height: 800,
  lineSpacing: 50,
  indentSpacing: 50,
  itemFont: '18px',
  boxSize: 10,
  tree_edge_thickness: 0.75,
  graph_edge_thickness: 1,
  linkStrength: 200,
  nodeStrength: -100,
  centreStrength: 80,
  theme: 'light',
  light_theme: {
    treeFill: 'white',
    scratchFill: 'ivory',
    promoFill: 'blanchedalmond',
    svgName: 'black',
    svgBorder: 'black',
    checkColour: 'gray',
    checkText: 'white',
    select: 'yellow',
    edges: 'black',
  },
  dark_theme: {
    treeFill: 'gray',
    scratchFill: 'dimgray',
    promoFill: 'gray',
    svgName: 'white',
    svgBorder: 'white',
    checkColour: 'white',
    checkText: 'gray',
    select: 'yellow',
    edges: 'white',
  },
};


const scratch = 'data/scratch.json';
d3.json(scratch).then(function (data) {
  console.log('scratch->', data);
  console.log('I am rendering the working page');

  //Step 1 - setup the SVG's

  let graphInitialiseOptions = window.workP.initSVG(
    data,
    options,
  );

  console.log(graphInitialiseOptions);

  //Return Step 1 Promise
  graphInitialiseOptions.then((initialiseResults) => {
    //Step 2 - split graph into PROMO and SCRATCH
    let updateDataOptions = window.workP.updateGraph(
      data,
      initialiseResults,
    );
    console.log(initialiseResults);

    // Return Step 2 Promise
    updateDataOptions.then((updateResults) => {
      //Step 3 - D3 draw
      let showGraphOptions =
        window.workP.showGraphs(updateResults);
      console.log(updateResults);

      // Return Step 3 Promise
      showGraphOptions.then((showResults) => {
        //Step 4 - D3 simulate graph
        let simOptions = window.workP.simGraph(showResults);

        simOptions.then((simResults) => {
          console.log(simResults);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});

The scratch.json data file that I use is too big to post here

Post text, not images. +700 lines of code is somewhat over the top. Reduce your code to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue. Then post it here (preferably as a runnable snippet) along with sample input, expected output, actual output plus any terminal/console warning or error messages (if any).

Yep sorry, well I have twin force graphs, so everything is doubled, but let me run through and check if i can reduce it

Sorry, I have cut out any of the commented code lines i had from before, and have culled the main file down to 550 lines for the Adjacency List Class and the four functions for two parallel force graphs. Its as much as i can do without significant altering of the code. Is that ok?
